Filter out and log null values from Spark dataframe
I have this dataframe :
+------+-------------------+-----------+
|brand |original_timestamp |weight     |
+------+-------------------+-----------+
|BR1   |1632899456         |4.0        |
|BR2   |1632899456         |null       |
|BR3   |1632899456         |2.0        |
|BR4   |1632899155         |2.0        |
|BR5   |1632899155         |null       |

I would like to drop (filter out) null values and print a message such as :
"Weight for brand BR2 is null, dropping it from the data"
"Weight for brand BR5 is null, dropping it from the data"
I am using Spark version 3.2.2 and SQLContext, with scala language.

What have you tried so far? And Do you want to drop the entire row or replace null value with something else?

I tried a UDF that takes in arguments the column brand and weight, and returns a boolean. Then I call it in a .filter. However, I get such error Schema for type AnyVal is not supported.
I would like to drop the entire row.

Can you share your code what you tried?

You have to use filter function with isNull & isNotNull to get desired output
Filter null values using isNull
df.filter($"weight".isNull).show(false)

+-----+------------------+------+
|brand|original_timestamp|weight|
+-----+------------------+------+
|BR2  |1632899456        |NULL  |
|BR5  |1632899155        |NULL  |
+-----+------------------+------+

Print message
df.filter($"weight".isNull)
.selectExpr("""
    concat(
       '\"Weight for brand ',
        brand, 
       ' is null, dropping it from the data\"'
    ) message
""")
.as[String]
.collect
.foreach(println)

"Weight for brand BR2 is null, dropping it from the data"
"Weight for brand BR5 is null, dropping it from the data"

Filter not null values using isNotNull
df.filter($"weight".isNotNull).show(false)

+-----+------------------+------+
|brand|original_timestamp|weight|
+-----+------------------+------+
|BR1  |1632899456        |4.0   |
|BR3  |1632899456        |2.0   |
|BR4  |1632899155        |2.0   |
+-----+------------------+------+

